# Custom, Dynamic Routing in WordPress | Timber Routes::load() Returns 404

Tags: wordpress, routes, timber

I've set up custom routing using Timber and the page loads and appears fine but the 404 template gets applied rather than the one given in `Routes::load()`.

There is some discussion on [this Github post](https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2446) that routing is deprecated. How can it be done now? How can I repurpose my existing Timber routing code to work using the new method?

Example structure of the routing code:

```
Routes::map('members/events/:category_name', function($params){

    // ...large amount of code here to alter params and prepare the query

    if (in_array($category, $countyCatsSlugs)) {
        Routes::load('page-events.php', $params, $query, 200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does your code located at `functions.php`? It is depends on file where code was placed. Your endpoint should be `functions.php`, relocate code within `functions.php` itself or any included file does it helps?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka ya this code is in functions.php. I had to remove Timber routes and use WordPress routing to pull it off.